# Highlight Code in Chat - Highlights <code> elements contained in chat messages

Tags: script, chat

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

Inspired by [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/167052/could-code-in-chat-markdown-with-backquotes-change-the-background-like-on-th) question, I have developed a UserScript that highlights `code` elements in chat messages so that they stand out more on the page. Simply install the script and your messages will be automatically highlighted.

#### License

The script is released under the [MIT License](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT).

#### Download

You can download the script in its entirety here:
http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/userscripts/code_highlight.user.js

### Contact

I can be reached at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`.

### Code

The UserScript is written in JavaScript.